# Can you do animations within an artboard when using the Sketch Prototyping feature?

Tags: sketch-app, animation, prototyping

We're trying to do animations within a single artboard in Sketch for prototyping.  Specifically, when a person clicks a button, we want the standard 'Share Sheet' to slide up from the bottom of the screen, covering the existing artboard.

The only animations that I'm aware of animate from one artboard to the next.  While I can somewhat simulate the final result I'm after using an instant transition to another artboard, then you have to worry about the alignment of the scroll position.

Are there any third-party plug-ins or any other ways to do what I'm after?

Answer (score 1):

Timeline and AnimateMate both offer animations directly within a single artboard in the Sketch App: [**AnimateMate**](http://animatemate.com/) is free, but still under heavy development, so treat like a beta, and [**Timeline**](https://timeline.animaapp.com/) is $39/mo for full usage, but free to prototype (no exports) and is pretty solidly developed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: These looked promising, especially Timeline since we don't need exporting, but unless I'm mistaken, the animation/interactions only run when you're in the Anima timeline editor, not Sketch's prototyping preview window, which is what we were hoping/looking for.  In other words, it's either/or, unless again, I'm wrong (which I'm hoping I am.)

Comment: Could you do this with Prototyping inbuilt into Sketch?